# Python: How make Ethereum tx without web3.py?

Tags: python

make a simple eth raw tx and self sign without web3

I only need generate a eth raw transaction and self sign , web3.py is bloated.

I generate lots of eth address using python like this:

```
def create_wallet():
    keccak = sha3.keccak_256()
    private_key = SigningKey.generate(curve=SECP256k1)
    public_key = private_key.get_verifying_key().to_string()

    keccak.update(public_key)

    address = '0x%s' % keccak.hexdigest()[24:]

    private_key = binascii.hexlify(private_key.to_string())
    public_key = binascii.hexlify(public_key)

    return {
        "private_key": private_key.decode(),
        "public_key": public_key.decode(),
        "address": address
    }
```

now i want make a simple raw transaction and sign it

Answer (score 2):

`eth-account` is the component that handles transaction signing in web3.py. You can install it directly with `pip install eth-account`.

Then you can [sign a transaction](https://eth-account.readthedocs.io/en/latest/eth_account.html#eth_account.account.Account.signTransaction) like so:

```
>>> from eth_account import Account

>>> transaction = {
        # Note that the address must be in checksum format, until this is resolved:
        # https://github.com/ethereum/eth-account/issues/32
        'to': '0xF0109fC8DF283027b6285cc889F5aA624EaC1F55',
        'value': 1000000000,
        'gas': 2000000,
        'gasPrice': 234567897654321,
        'nonce': 0,
        'chainId': 1
    }
>>> key = '0x4c0883a69102937d6231471b5dbb6204fe5129617082792ae468d01a3f362318'

>>> signed = Account.signTransaction(transaction, key)
{'hash': HexBytes('0x6893a6ee8df79b0f5d64a180cd1ef35d030f3e296a5361cf04d02ce720d32ec5'),
 'r': 4487286261793418179817841024889747115779324305375823110249149479905075174044,
 'rawTransaction': HexBytes('0xf86a8086d55698372431831e848094f0109fc8df283027b6285cc889f5aa624eac1f55843b9aca008025a009ebb6ca057a0535d6186462bc0b465b561c94a295bdb0621fc19208ab149a9ca0440ffd775ce91a833ab410777204d5341a6f9fa91216a6f3ee2c051fea6a0428'),  # noqa: E501
 's': 30785525769477805655994251009256770582792548537338581640010273753578382951464,
 'v': 37}

>>> w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed.rawTransaction)
```